# How to change HTML table cell value (ie: if i enter quantity in the text box it should reflect qty colm of pol(last table value ) ) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I need to get the value from the textbox(Discount or quantity) and need to change the last column value of the quantity or discount in the table

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Quantity</b></h5>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Discount</b></h5>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Discount" placeholder="Discount">
</div>

<table id="sales_table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableheader">
      <th style="width:40px">#</th>
      <th style="width:250px">Item Name</th>
      <th style="width:120px">Price</th>
      <th style="width:60px">Disc %</th>
      <th style="width:60px">Qty</th>
      <th style="width:60px">GST %</th>
      <th style="width:60px">GST AMT</th>
      <th style="width:60px">CGST %</th>
      <th style="width:60px">CGST AMT</th>
      <th style="width:120px">Total</th>
      <th style="width:px"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:php] and [tag:html] tags since you're asking how to do this with JavaScript. This isn't a PHP or HTML question.

Comment: which column will be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

this will capture the input and place it in a new row.  just enter a number for quantity and hit enter.  duplicate code for discount.

```js
    
   


    








var quantInput = document.getElementById('Quantity');




quantInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
 // Cancel the default action, if needed
    // event.preventDefault();
 // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
 if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var   quantity =document.getElementById("Quantity");
   
   var table = document.getElementById("sales_table");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell = new Array(11);
    var length= document.getElementById("sales_table").rows.length;   
    var row = table.insertRow(length);
    
    for(var i = 0; i<11;i++){
     cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
    }
   
   cell[4].innerHTML = quantity.value;
   document.getElementById("Quantity").value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">

                <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Quantity</b></h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Quantity"  placeholder="Quantity" >   
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Discount</b></h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Discount"  placeholder="Discount">   
            </div>  

    <table id="sales_table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="tableheader">
                                <th style="width:40px">#</th>

                                <th style="width:250px">Item Name</th>

                                <th style="width:120px">Price</th>

                                <th style="width:60px">Disc %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">Qty</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">GST %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">GST AMT</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">CGST %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">CGST AMT</th>
                                <th style="width:120px">Total</th>
                                <th style="width:px"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Thank You for your replay. while adding Quantity its adding new column. What I need is to change the existing quantity of last quantity value.

Comment: i don't understand.  You have a blank table with just a row of th's  What exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Quantity = document.getElementById('Quantity')
let Discount = document.getElementById('Discount')

   Quantity.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
        document.querySelector('.tableheader > .columnQty').innerText = 'Qty '+ e.target.value +'%';

    },false) 
    Discount.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
       document.querySelector('.tableheader > .columnDisc').innerText = 'Disc '+ e.target.value +'%';
    },false)
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">

                <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Quantity</b></h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Quantity"  placeholder="Quantity">   
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5 class="bordercool"><b>Discount</b></h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="Discount"  placeholder="Discount">   
            </div>  

    <table id="sales_table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="tableheader">
                                <th style="width:40px">#</th>

                                <th style="width:250px">Item Name</th>

                                <th style="width:120px">Price</th>

                                <th style="width:60px" class='columnDisc'>Disc %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px" class='columnQty'>Qty</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">GST %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">GST AMT</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">CGST %</th>
                                <th style="width:60px">CGST AMT</th>
                                <th style="width:120px">Total</th>
                                <th style="width:px" class="changedItem"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Thank You for your replay! I don't want to change the header. Instead of that I need to change the last value of discount column